# @Media with the "Min-Width" Property

Tags: html, google-chrome, zooming, css

I'm trying something new, which is `@media all and (min-width: 60em)`.  [Here is what I have.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bionicrm/zYm8t/)  The problem I'm having is in **Chrome**, which is surprising.

What's happening is when you zoom out (or from the start if you have a decent sized screen), "Join" and "Create" turn to "Join Room" and "Create Room", respectively (which is good).  However, in Chrome, when you zoom back in, you must zoom in a little *past* the point that it previously changed to "Join Room" and "Create Room" to see the regular "Join" and "Create" again.  This also happens the other way around, too.

Sorry if it's confusing, but hopefully the jsFiddle helps.

Comment: the "em" unit used this way seems really strange to me, could you consider using fixed pixel width instead ? something like 1000px gives me a nice and consistent "changing point" when zooming in and out in chrome.

Comment: Sure, but would that ensure that it will change to "Join Room" & "Create Room" at the right time if the user changes their font size settings?

Comment: I cannot duplicate your experience. No matter how wide I make the window, I never need, for instance, two "Zoom In"s after one "Zoom Out" that changes the text. Which version of Chrome and which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, Chrome 28.  If I have to change the units to "px", would that ensure that no matter how big the text size is, it will change appropriately?